# Can't boot into Ubuntu with extra hard drive

Tags: boot

I have a SSD 60GB with Ubuntu. And it was working all right.

Then I decided to add one more hard drive. It was previously in a different PC under win Xperia. Then I cleaned it and formatted it, so it's empty. But if I add it to this PC, I can't boot into Ubuntu. The process stops after recognizing ram and proc.

With this configuration I even can't get into BIOS. If I unplug the second disk Ubuntu works again. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your bios settings to check the correct boot sequence. You have to be sure that the first storage is your SSD where you have installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I can do it only with the ssd only. Because when I try to boot with the additional drive , it even doesn't let me in bios

Comment: This is normal. You can boot from only one hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. You can boot from only one hard drive. 
This is what I understood into your question: You have a desktop PC in which you have placed a SSD, this is not a USB drive but it is connected straight on the motherboard via the approprate cable. Then you connect another HDD even on the motherboard into another free connection and after this the PC don't boot in the way you are expecting. If I'm right still here, what you have to do is switch on the PC pushing the "del" or "backwords" button to open the bios settings then, looking for the boot sequence then, select as a primary boot device your SSD then, check there are no other devices specified for booting the system (CD-ROM is good to left as a second chance) then, be sure to save the settings changes then, boot the PC

Comment: You are right. But the problem is that as I connect the second drive (which is empty and formated ) and than restart and try do get into bios, it just doesn't go there. It's just starts the process and then stops after determining the proc and ram. For some misterious reason I can't get into bios. If I switch it off, unconnect the HDD, everything works just fine. And in bios I have boot from ssd.

Comment: Check on the hard disk if there are pins to select it as a slave/master/cable select. If there are and it's set as a master try with the other options.

Comment: Can't see any pins. And did I say that I've tried another combination: another disk with windows plus this one (empty) (without SSD) and it works just fine.

Comment: This is what I mean [link](http://www.pcguide.com/byop/byop_SettingHardDriveJumpers.htm)

Comment: Oh,got it. I'll have a look when back in the city. Thank you very much

Comment: I've just got a chance to have a look. And unfortunately there's no pins on the disk. Do you think I should put one?